# Is there an in-universe reason how Princess Leia kept herself and her hair so tightly groomed during the events of the Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars, character-motivation, princess-leia

In A New Hope, we see Princess Leia in her signature "cinnamon" buns:
[image: >https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1b/Princess_Leia%27s_characteristic_hairstyle.jpg]

On present-day Earth, that hairstyle is very difficult to maintain:

> The iconic if ludicrous hairdo—Carrie Fisher, who starred as Leia, herself mocked it as “cinnamon buns”—took two hours to style and secure, and even then, it was dodgy. “I was a little afraid of it,” Fisher told The Making of Star Wars author J.W. Rinzler. “I was afraid my hair was going to fall off.” ([source](https://www.thevintagenews.com/2017/12/03/princess-leias-hairstyle/))

Yet, Fisher, as Leia, kept the hairstyle all through the events of the first movie, despite her being trapped in prison, locked in  a trash compacter, and involved in battle, among other things. [Her other hairstyles](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/a-complete-timeline-of-princess-leias-hair-from-184017223.html) in the other movies, and other grooming traits - i.e. lipstick and makeup - remained unaffected as well.

I understand that it's a movie and George Lucas wanted Carrie Fisher to look her best. But is there an in-universe reason how the hairstyle stayed perfect throughout the events of the first movie? Does the Star Wars universe have some sort of self-grooming tech?

(Inspired by this quote on [Mental Floss](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/63284/brief-history-princess-leias-buns):

> “When would revolutionaries find the time to put your hair up in two ridiculous buns, which are impossible, even with modern state-of-the-art hair product technology to carry for any length of time, if indeed you manage to tame your hair enough to play along to begin with.” )

Comment: "[With a Danish on each ear, and Darth Vader drawing near](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX3sI0q5iMI)"

Comment: seems like a good job for protocol droid....

Comment: It's a common misconception that's her hair, those are actually ear muffs.

Comment: The Force is a pathway to fashions that some would consider...unnatural.

Comment: All the technological resources the GFFA didn't expend on paper and women's undergarments went in to coiffure.

Comment: I had thought that Princess Leia hairstyle was inspired in a work of Leonardo da Vici called "Study for the Head of Leda".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In her younger days she used to just have a serving droid do it.

> “Another dinner party,” she groused as 2V slid a soft blue wrap around
> the shoulders of her white gown. “How many has my mom thrown this
> year? A dozen? Twenty?”
> “Fourteen. Now, hold still. These are the old-fashioned pins that can
> still stick you.” 2V adroitly fastened the wrap in place with two
> jeweled brooches, one at each shoulder. They sparkled prettily, but
> Leia couldn’t have cared less. “I think two side buns tonight. Do you
> agree, Your Highness?”
> “Whatever.”
> 2V tilted her torso forward to study her charge, perhaps thinking such insensitivity to fashion was evidence of an imminent collapse. **Leia simply sat down at the vanity to let the droid do her work.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Leia: Princess of Alderaan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leia,_Princess_of_Alderaan)</sup></sub>

Once she went on the run, I see no reason why one of the Rebellion's various [protocol droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/K-3PO) couldn't learn how to tie them for her.

---

Note that although this hairstyle looks a little fussy to us, the style is described as "*elaborate but efficient*" by a stormtrooper, indicating that by Empire standards, her hairstyle may be quite easy to put together, albeit time-consuming.

> Her clothing was so white as to almost glow, her skin smooth and pale
> as cream. As pale as his own, though **her long, glossy hair, gathered
> up in elaborate but efficient twin buns on either side of her face**,
> was a rich warm brown, not the bright, sunny yellow of his.
>
> <sub><sup>[From a Certain Point of View: The Bucket](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Bucket)</sup></sub>